# Import data from text file with copy command in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I created table with 3 columns: DocumentID, SentenceId, Sentence. I want to assign DocumentId myself, SentenceID to increment itself and to insert data from text file into column sentence omitting first numbers. For Example there is a text in a text file:

```
0,189   A   few years   ago ,   when    I   was looking at  middle  schools for my  daughter. 
190,412 Having  reported    on  a   vogue   for single-sex  classrooms  in  the nineties.
```

After importing this text file in a table I want to get something like this:

```
DocumentID | SentenceID | Sentence  
123        |     1      | A few years ago, when...  
123        |     2      | Having reported on a vogue....
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `copy foobar (third_column) from 'some_file.txt'`?

Comment: For example I have text:  "0,189 A few years ago , when I was looking at middle schools for my daughter". I want to copy this from text file and to get something like this: DocId 123 SentenceID 1 Sencence "A few years ago" without 0,189.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please **edit** your question and add some sample lines from the file as _formatted_ text, the `create table` statement for your table (as _formatted_ text) and the resulting content in the table (again as _formatted_ text)

Comment: I edited. There are 47 lines, each start with pointers like 0,189 190,220 221,300. I want to import data without them.